# Get user input from HTML form, Display and let user confirm their input in php, and then store their input into a text file

Tags: php, html, text-files, user-input, store

I wrote a  HTML form in bws.html for user to input the records. After clicking 'submit' button, the form will direct to form_action.php. It will display user input and let user check their input. After they confirm and click 'confirm and save' button, the user input will store into a text file.

However, when i clicked 'confirm and save' button, it directed to a new web page and only show those two buttons I have made in form_action.php. It didn't generate a new text file 'data.txt' automatically in my document root directory of the Apache web server.

I am a newbie in html and php. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks so much for your help.

Here are my html form and php code:

bws html:

```
<h1 style="font-size:36px"><a name="employee_records"><center>
    Employee Records</center></a></h1>
<form action="form_action.php" method="post" style="margin-left:26px; margin-right:26px">
    <h2><center>Records input form</center></h2>
    Employee Number: <input type="text" name="employee_number"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Employee Name: <input type="text area" name="employee_name"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Job Title:
        <select name="job_title" id="job_title">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="PRESIDENT">PRESIDENT</option>
            <option value="MANAGER">MANAGER</option>
            <option value="SALESMAN">SALESMAN</option>
            <option value="ANALYST">ANALYST</option>
            <option value="CLERK">CLERK</option>
        </select>
    <br/><br/>
    Employee Supervisor's number: <input type="text" 
        name="employee_supervisor_number"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="date_of_starting_work">Date of Starting Work:</label>
    <input type="date" name="working_date" id="date_of_starting_work"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        Employee Salary:<br/>
        <input type="range" min="10000" max="90000" value="50000" 
            class="slider" name="salary" id="salary">
        Value: $<span id="value"></span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <label for="commission" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;">
        <span style="color:red;">*</span>Employee Commission: </label>
        <input type="text" name="commission" id="employee_commission"/>
    <br/><br/>
    Department Number:<br/><br/>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="department_number" value="Department Number: 10<br><br> 
                Department Name: ACCOUNTING<br><br> Location: New York<br><br>"/></td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>ACCOUNTING</td>
            <td>New York</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="department_number" value="Department Number: 20<br><br> 
                Department Name: RESEARCH<br><br> Location: Dallas<br><br>"/></td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>RESEARCH</td>
            <td>Dallas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="department_number" value="Department Number: 30<br><br>
                Department Name: SALES<br><br> Location: Chicago<br><br>"/></td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>SALES</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="department_number" value="Department Number: 40<br><br> 
                Department Name: OPERATIONS<br><br> Location: Boston<br><br>"/></td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>OPERATIONS</td>
            <td>Boston</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="Best Web Services"/>
</form>
<hr/>
<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("salary");
    var output = document.getElementById("value");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

form_action.php:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $number = $_POST["employee_number"];
    $name = $_POST["employee_name"];
    $jobtitle = $_POST["job_title"];
    $Snumber = $_POST["employee_supervisor_number"];
    $date = $_POST["working_date"];
    $salary = $_POST["salary"];
    $commission = $_POST["commission"];
    $Dnumber = $_POST["department_number"];
    
    echo "<br>";
    if (empty($number)) {
        echo "<b>Employee number is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Employee Number: $number <br><br>";
    }
    
    if (empty($name)) {
        echo "<b>Employee name is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Employee Name: $name <br><br>";
    }

    if (empty($jobtitle)) {
        echo "<b>Job title is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Job Title: $jobtitle <br><br>";
    }

    if (empty($Snumber)) {
        echo "<b>Employee supervisor's number is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Employee Supervisor's Number: $Snumber <br><br>";
    }

    if (empty($date)) {
        echo "<b>Date of starting work is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Date of Starting Work: $date <br><br>";
    }

    if (empty($salary)) {
        echo "<b>Employee salary is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Employee Salary: $$salary <br><br>";
    }

    if (empty($commission)) {
        echo "<b>Employee commission is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Employee Commission: $$commission <br><br>";
    }

    if (empty($Dnumber)) {
        echo "<b>Department number is required.</b><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "$Dnumber <br><br>";
    }

    echo "Please click 'Confirm and Save' button if your input is correct. <br><br>";
    echo "Otherwise, please click 'Back' button to go back to the form. <br><br>";
    
    if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
    $file = fopen("data.txt", "w+") or die("file can't open");
    fwrite($file, "Employee Number: ");
    fwrite($file, $number . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fwrite($file, "Employee Name: ");
    fwrite($file, $name . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fwrite($file, "Job Title: ");
    fwrite($file, $jobtitle . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fwrite($file, "Employee Supervisor's Number: ");
    fwrite($file, $Snumber . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fwrite($file, "Date of Starting Work: ");
    fwrite($file, $date . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fwrite($file, "Employee Salary: $");
    fwrite($file, $salary . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fwrite($file, "Employee Commission: $");
    fwrite($file, $commission . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fwrite($file, "Department Number: ");
    fwrite($file, $Dnumber . "\n") or die("Data can't write");
    fclose($file);
    }
}

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Confirm and Save"/>
<button onclick="goBack()">Back</button></form>
```

Comment: Hi, when you click `Confirm and Save`, The old data from `bws.html` does not exist

Comment: So how can I retrieve and save the user input in bws.html using the Confirm and Save button in php?